# ionic 2 TypeError: self.context.doInfinite is not a function

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to load more data from the server and i am getting error in a console

```
zone.js:260 

Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error in build/pages/home/home.html:30:23
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: self.context.doInfinite is not a function
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: self.context.doInfinite is not a function
    at DebugAppView._View_HomePage0._handle_ionInfinite_25_0..
```

home.ts has the following codes

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {JobService} from '../job/job';
import {JobPage} from '../services/JobService';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  providers:[JobService]
})

export class HomePage {
    public posts:any = [];
    private start:number=0;
    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, public peopleService:PeopleService) {
      this.loadPeople();
    }

    loadPeople() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.peopleService.load(this.start)
      .then(data => {
        for(let kazitz of data) {
          this.posts.push(kazitz);
        } 
        resolve(true);
      });     
    });
    }

    doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
     console.log('doInfinite, start is currently '+this.start);
     this.start+=5;
     this.loadPeople().then(()=>{
       infiniteScroll.complete();
     });  
    }   
}
```

Now, error says `doInfinite is not a function` while it is a function you see above, i am getting this error while the app tries to load more data.. in home.html normal ionic 2 load more codes i took from [ionic framework docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/)

```
  <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles"
      loadingText="Loading more...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hi JohnPep. If you solved the problem please add the solution as answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and it only worked when i added this.doInfinite(); to the Constructor() like this:

```
Constructor(){
    this.doInfinite();
}
```

I cannot guarantee it will work, and I apologise if it doesn't. I am honestly still perplexed by it. Good luck!